# Composer won't install even though there's no apparent conflict

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've been struggling with this issue for a while. I'm upgrading from Laravel 6 to 7, and composer is not cooperating here. It outputs an enormous dependency story which doesn't make any sense to me at all.

I made sure my dependencies support Laravel 7.0, and I might've missed something, but composer is surely not highlighting it if I did.

I removed `composer.lock` and `vendor` as well.

Here's my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my/app",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://nova.laravel.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.3.0",
        "geoip2/geoip2": "^2.9",
        "imdbphp/imdbphp": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/horizon": "^4.0",
        "laravel/nova": "^3.0",
        "laravel/scout": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "nothingworks/blade-svg": "^0.3.3",
        "php-tmdb/api": "^2.1",
        "pmatseykanets/laravel-scout-postgres": "^7.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "protoqol/prequel": "dev-master",
        "sokil/php-isocodes": "^3.0",
        "spatie/image": "^1.7.6",
        "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.2",
        "torann/geoip": "^1.2.1",
        "vinkla/hashids": "^8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.7",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^4.1.3",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I execute `composer install`, it takes around 3 minutes (with `xdebug` disabled), and outputs this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.1.0-BETA1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher 5.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher 5.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.0-BETA2|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.0-RC1|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.0|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.1|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.2|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.3|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.4|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.5|install symfony/event-dispatcher 4.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.0-BETA1
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ^2.7 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.7.0].
    - Installation request for protoqol/prequel dev-master -> satisfiable by protoqol/prequel[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install php-tmdb/api 2.1.x-dev|don't install symfony/console 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
```

...and a few **megabytes** of "Conclusion: don't install|Conclusion: install" messages in between...

```
- Installation request for php-tmdb/api ^2.1 -> satisfiable by php-tmdb/api[2.1.0, 2.1.16, 2.1.17, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.x-dev, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.14, v2.1.15, v2.1.9].      
    - laravel/framework v7.0.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.2 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.3 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.4 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.5 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.6 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.7 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.0.8 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.1.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.1.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.1.2 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.1.3 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.2.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.2.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.2.2 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.3.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.4.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.5.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - laravel/framework v7.5.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel 5.0.x-dev requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.0 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.0-BETA1 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, 
v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.0-BETA2 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, 
v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.0-RC1 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.1 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.2 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.3 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.4 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.5 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.6 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.7 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.0.8 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel v5.1.0-BETA1 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, 
v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - symfony/http-kernel 5.1.x-dev requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.1.0-BETA1].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.2|install symfony/event-dispatcher v5.0.0-BETA1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Seems like it says `laravel/framework` wants to include `symfony/http-kernel` and `symfony/http-kernel` wants to include `symfony/event-dispatcher`, but I don't understand what's wrong with that? Why is it even an error?

Comment: how did you try to upgrade to the newest version? Can you share the composer.json file?

Comment: Please share more details. Without knowing the current content of your `composer.json`, its close to impossible to provide help

Comment: @DavidHlavati Sorry, I updated the question with my `composer.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the conclusion list, it tells you it wants to install `php-tmdb/api: 2.1.x-dev`.

If you go to that project's repo, you'll notice there's a v3 available.

v2 of `php-tmdb/api` wants `"symfony/event-dispatcher": ">=2.4,<5"` - that collides with laravel's constraint.

Solution: require `php-tmdb/api: 3.0`

https://github.com/php-tmdb/api/releases

Comment: Genius! Thanks! Why doesn't composer let me know that? There's not even a line in the log that says `tmdb/api` requires `event-dispatcher`.. Do I really have to manually go over each package's composer.json and validate myself?

Comment: There are lines that say `symfony/http-kernel vXXX requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^XXX` but no lines that say `php-tmdb/api vXXX requires symfony/event-dispatcher ^xxx`

Comment: @MosheRevah I read the "Conclusion" part of the message you posted and it mentions the library there, which is why I went and checked it out on Github. I agree it could be done better, but hey - you can't expect miracles. It is a PITA to debug these, however you get the hang of it as time goes by. Glad you sorted it!